# I am compiling an e-commerce application, but I am getting the following errors in the gradle console

Tags: java, android

**I am compiling an e-commerce application, but I am getting the following errors in the gradle console:**

```
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
 at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
 at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
 at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException: 1 exception was raised by workers:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

 at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:108)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:67)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicateClassesTask.doTaskAction(CheckDuplicateClassesTask.kt:61)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
 at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
 at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
 at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
 at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
 ... 38 more
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
 at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:102)
 ... 102 more
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)
 Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)

 Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
 at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:128)
 at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:68)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
 ... 103 more
```

**below my build.gradle**

```
<pre>
    buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.3'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'br.com.coalaresolve.appvale'

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "ad359056-018a-4db5-ae4f-915e177adf87",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 7
    versionName '3.1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
}
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.6'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Whenever I am going to compose this error it is presented to me, I have already installed AndroidStudio on another machine but it continues to present the error message, I no longer know what to do.

**New Error:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
...

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)

... 38 more
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't actually shown the error - just *part* of a stack trace, which doesn't include an error message. Please include more details.

Comment: My *guess* is that the missing `}` of `defaultConfig {` is causing the error. --- And presumably, there is something before the `compileSdkVersion` line. Or is it just very bad indentations?

Comment: I updated the question with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is

> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.1.0-runtime.jar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) and support-compat-26.0.0-runtime.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0)

In order to solve it you should enable Jetifier in ur `gradle.properties` file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Normally you should **not** have `support library` and `androidx` dependencies in one project

Jetifier will replace support dependency to equal androidx dependency automatically

Comment: I did as you said, this time presented a new error, I put a copy up there in the question.

Comment: I did what you asked and remove 

```compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

deverything went ok. Thank you very much, it was of great value for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you asked and remove

```
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8 targetCompatibility = 1.6 }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3' 

deverything went ok. Thank you very much, it was of great value for your help.
```